# Asp.net Build error?

Tags: asp.net

when i run the my asp.net application it is showing this message can u help me.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @Surya ->Version 1 ? are you sure you need that, now the version is 3.5 or 4. Maybe a not good MS Ajax installation ? What version of asp.net are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether referenced assembly (System.Web.Extensions.Design) exists in GAC or Bin folder of your app.